# RPIO PWM and AfroESC

Tags: pi-3, pwm, rpio

I'm working on a quadcopter controlled by a Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm having some issues controlling the Electronic Speed Control (ESC). I'm a bit of a newbie so please be patient.

I bought the [Afro Race Spec Mini 20Amp Multi-Rotor Speed Controller with BEC](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/afro-race-spec-mini-20amp-multi-rotor-speed-controller-with-bec.html) that is supposed to work with a 1Khz freq, and I managed to control the speed of the motor using the [GPIO.PWM module](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/PWM/) with poor results: the signal sent apparently is not very accurate and the motor spinning is quite noisy and irregular.

Then I switched to the [RPIO module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPIO) and after many nights I managed to make it work with the Raspberry Pi 3 by cloning the metachris version:

```
git clone https://github.com/metachris/RPIO.git --branch v2 --single-branch
```

The code I'm trying to use is something like:

```
import time
from RPIO import PWM

PIN = 18

servo = PWM.Servo() #using default pulse with 20ms -> 50Hz

servo.set_servo(PIN, 1200)
time.sleep(5)

servo.stop_servo(PIN)
```

I was expecting some kind of movement of the motor but nothing is happening.

Since the ESC is supposed to work at 1Khz frequency, should I set the pulse width accordingly? In this case should be:

```
 servo = PWM.Servo(1000)
```

If so, I can't do this because the minimum value appears to be 3000 microseconds.

Can I do anything to overcome this issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Also, during a series of tests I managed to control the motor setting:

```
servo = PWM.Servo(8000)
```

and changing the servo with random values:

```
servo.set_servo(PIN, random_value)
```

but I'm not able to replicate how I did it!

My questions are:

- If the ESC is supposed to work with a 1000Hz frequency how come did it work with a pulse-width 8000 -> basically 125 Hz ?
- Is there something I'm missing? ESC calibration, wrong values or anything?

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try the following from the command line.  I'm assuming you mean Broadcom GPIO 18 (pin 12).

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon

pigs pfs 18 1000 # set 1kHz PWM on GPIO 18
pigs prs 18 1000 # set duty cycle range 0-1000, (same as micros)

pigs p 18 500 # send 500 micro pulses
pigs p 18 200 # send 200 micro pulses
pigs p 18 700 # send 700 micro pulses
```

Experiment with the pulse lengths.

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion has been really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment from joan I was able to make it work and I want to share my solution.
Apparently it's all about calibrating/initializing the ESC.

In my example I've used the library PIGPIO that you can find at
http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/

Once you install the library and start the daemon with

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon
```

you're ready to send signals to the GPIO pins.
In my case I set the frequency to 1Khz and the range 0-1000

```
pigs pfs 18 1000 # set 1kHz PWM on GPIO 18
pigs prs 18 1000 # set duty cycle range 0-1000, (same as micros)
```

Then you need to find the right pulse in order to initialise your ESC.
After many attempts I found the value 155 was good for mine.

```
pigs p 18 155 #send 155 micro pulses
```

This initialises the ESC and you can hear a long beep indicating the ESC is ready to work.

From now on any value in the range 165-300 let the motor move at a specific speed (the steps are 5 micro pulses, so 165-170-175...)

Hope it helps someone else as well.

Comment: Just a couple of notes.  You can use servoblaster and RPIO.GPIO as well as pigpio to control servos/ESCs.  The pigs utility is useful for testing.  If you need better resolution you can start the pigpiod daemon with 2, or 4 µs steps (-s option).  Servoblaster and RPIO.GPIO will have similar options.